# Trying to make my jquery arrow img change to different arrow on Hide/Show content

Tags: jquery, html, css, toggle

I have this very simple JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".neverseen img").click(function() {
    $(".neverseen p").slideToggle("slow");
    return false;
  });
});
```

And this HTML

```
<div class="neverseen">
  <h1>Title to always show</h1>
  <a href="#" id="show">
    <img src="images/demo/arrow.png" width="40" height="40">
  </a>
  <p>Text to toggle hide/show</p>
</div>
```

So what I need is to add another image called arrow2.png that will replace the first arrow when hidden content activates or make the current arrow turn 180 degrees. I have tried different jquery methods but nothing seems to work so well.

Another thing I wish is to have a border-bottom that is visible at all times and moves with the hidden content so the border is below the title on hidden and below the content on visible, whatever I am doing here results in double borders.

Comment: Add this in your `click` function: `$(this).css('transform','rotate(180deg)')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have different solutions to achieve that, here is one of them:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".neverseen img").click(function() {
   $(this).parent().toggleClass("active");
   $(".neverseen p").slideToggle("slow");
     return false;
    });
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 50px;
}

#secondImage {
  display: none;
}

.active #firstImg {
  display:none;
}

.active #secondImage {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="neverseen">
<h1>Title to always show</h1>
<a href="#" id="show">
<img id="secondImage" src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSWdFg2vU1YX0W8HGMurPjTOSsOf8rwadUWNwPV6I_7NsDJ3nnURSSzIcw" width="40" height="40">
 <img id="firstImg" src="https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/arrow-top-ios-7-interface-symbol_318-34757.jpg" alt="">
</a>
<p>
  Text to toggle hide/show <hr class="to-be-hidden">  
  </p> 
</div>
```

I would suggest you to use [bootstrap collapse](http://www.w3schools.com/Bootstrap/bootstrap_collapse.asp), it is really amazing!

Comment: Tested and it worked great, you don't have any idea regarding getting the bottom-border working as i described in the post?

Comment: Have you ever used bootstrap collapse? For your case, it really would help you! Take a look: http://www.w3schools.com/Bootstrap/bootstrap_collapse.asp @FilipPetersson

Comment: @TeautaKoraqi No i have never used it but it looks very promising will definetely take a hard look at that! thanks for the tip.

Comment: Just download bootstrap.min.js and bootsrap.min.css, and follow the instructions. I have used many times, so you can use it without no worries.  If you need any help, just comment here, and I will help you! :) @FilipPetersson

Comment: @FilipPetersson, I made a fiddle for you using bootstrap collapse: https://jsfiddle.net/teutakoraqi/xhjkv1j3/20/

Answer (score 0):

Fairly simple procedure using **jQuery**'s native `.css()` function. No need to substitute with a completely different image

Try this instead:

```
$(".neverseen img").click(function() {
    $(this).css("transform", "rotate(180deg)"); // rotate the image 180 degrees once it has been clicked
    $(".neverseen p").slideToggle("slow");

    return false;
});
```

**EDIT**: to achieve a continuous result & the bottom border, within your **jQuery** try something like this:

```
$(".neverseen img").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("open");
    $(".neverseen p").slideToggle("slow");

    if($(this).hasClass("open")){
        $("h1").css("border-bottom", "none");
        $(this).css("border-bottom", "1px solid black");
    } else {
        $("h1").css("border-bottom", "1px solid black");
        $(this).css("border-bottom", "none");
    }

    return false;
});
```

and then, inside of your **CSS**:

```
h1{
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
.neverseen img{
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    transition: transform 500ms; // rotate for 500 milliseconds
}
.open{
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

Comment: This does indeed work to rotate the arrow once but if i toggle it again it wont rotate, i want it to rotate everytime i toggle show/hide.

Comment: @FilipPetersson one moment! :)

Comment: @FilipPetersson try it now :-)

Comment: This also worked great thanks. I also tested the bottom border solution but i also thought of that but the thing is that when the logo rotates the img  border turns upside down so it gets weird. You have any other ideas there? :)

Comment: @FilipPetersson think i might have fixed your problem :) try it now

Comment: 2 current issues with that solution. 1: the bottom border on the h1 is always there and its placed directly under the title, i would like some space between the h1 and the bottom border.  2: the bottom border doesnt go away when i show the hidden content.